# 18.04 - Remove/Hide box around current icon

Tags: icons, customization, dock

How can I remove the grey/transparent box around the icon of the application I'm using in Ubuntu dock? When multiple applications are running, the dock displays an indicator (a dot, but I can customize it) but also a grey box around the icon of the application I'm using at the moment. I want to remove it
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/COzYa.jpg)! 
e.g. In this image I'm using Nautilus and the box sorrounds the icon in the dock. If I open firefox, the box goes on its icon while I'm using it and so on.

Comment: Wouldn't you mind to attach a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: @user3417815 done

Comment: Thas is a nice build-in indication of the currently active app.

Comment: @vanadium I know this is not a bug or something, but I don't like it and I'd like to remove it

Comment: I'm am using the stock Gnome session, and there there is no such highlight even with Ubuntu Dock enabled. That may be related to the shell theme. In tweaks, you could try to set the Shell theme to default and disable the extension "User themes". That will also change the appearance of your top bar and calendar. I do not see specific settings in dconf-editor, so any other approach may require editing directly editing css style sheets.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work @vanadium

Comment: OK, strange that on my setup, I cannot even *add* the grey box. Probably would need to log in to the Ubuntu session to see it.

Comment: Can you please show me your setup?